# Remove zeros after point (euro comma separator).php

Tags: php, woocommerce, euro

I need to remove zeros after the point (euro comma separator) in functions.php (in a WooCommerce site).

Example: in a cart under total value it shows `999,700€` and I need it to show `999,7€`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer enough. 1. Are you dealing with strings or floating numbers? 2. Do you know how to program? A general idea for your issue is: finding `€` first; then look for `0`s from `€` to the left; then remove this substring from the original string. The idea is very clear, you can search for detailed information easily.

Answer (score 0):

Please Go to WooCommerce->General Settings and there you will find **Number of decimals** Setting. Reduce its value to 1. So it will display price in your shop up to 1 decimal places as desired by you.